# I belong to Swat vs I hail from Swat

Tags: sentence-construction

I know that most of the people use "I belong to ABC" but I have seen "He is hailing from Mardan". So, Is there any difference?

Also, can I say "I belong to Swat"  or "I belong to Mingora"?  Swat is the name of my district while Mingora is the city where I live.

Comment: "Belong to" is more often used for a company than a country.  "Hailing from" would be from a country.

Comment: What do you mean by company?

Comment: If I work for Walmart, I might say "I belong to Walmart".  I would not say "I belong to Italy".

Comment: Ouch — I wouldn't say that I "belong" to an employer, except perhaps sarcastically.

Comment: @mattdm: belong to: "be a member of (a particular group or organization)"

Comment: @JavaLatte Yes, but at least in the US, we don't generally consider employment to be that kind of relationship. You might belong to a club, a church, or a secret society, but you don't belong to a company you work for.

Comment: Can i say;  I belong to Swat or  I belong to Mingora (My residence)

Comment: @mattdm: In the UK, we make a distinction between belonging to a person "to be someone's ​property" and belonging to something  "be a member of (a particular group or organization)". It's a small but important distinction.

Comment: Swat is the name of my district while mingora the city where I live.

Answer (score 1):

You do not "belong to" a country. 
It is possible to say: "I belong here", meaning: I feel at home here and I will always live here. 
"Hailing from" is formal and also a little bit old-fashioned. 
"I am from" remains the best option, and also "I am originally from..." if you want to give the idea of origins/ roots.

Comment: In what sense is *hailing from* formal?

Comment: @AlanCarmack OLD lists it as formal-> http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hail-from

Answer (score 1):

In American English, one would usually just say

> 1 I am from Mingora, Swat.
>
> 2 I am from Swat. I am from the Switzerland of the East. I am from Pakistan.

We don't usually say

> ? 3 I come from somewhere.

But we can say that to stress that we are not from the place that we are currently in.

> 4 I come from Mingora, remember, and people from Mingora have different customs than the people here do.

In American English we rarely say

> ?5 I belong to a place or to a company.

I do know where you heard *I belong to ABC*, but this is not the normal way in American English to say

> 6 I work for ABC.

*Hail from* indicates origin, as in

> 7 She hails from Mingora, Swat

Two answers here have labelled *hail from* as 'formal'. However most dictionaries of American English do not indicate this. And as a native speaker of American English, I would not call *hail from* 'formal'.   See also my question on ELU: [Is *hail from* necessarily formal?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317307/is-hail-from-somewhere-necessarily-formal-english). I have included links in that question to dictionaries which say *hail from* is formal. (Thanks to Khan for those links.)

To me, *hail from* sounds colloquial, something that Mark Twain, in informal usage, might say. But many newspapers and magazines use it today.

Comment: @Khan I am surprised any dictionary would describe *hail from* as formal. To me it is decidedly colloquial. But that's just me. Maybe it's considered formal in British English. The OED does not mark it as such. And I asked an open-ended question on ELU regarding this issue. I appreciate the dialog with you about it.

Comment: I can't say much about the OED because I don't have it in print, but I have a hunch that it doesn't mark any word whatsoever as "formal". (I just asked someone to have a quick check on *commence* in the OED. Nothing is said about its formality. But your edition could be different.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. True, I don't know/recall if OED marks for formality or not. I'm pretty sure it does for colloquial (which it does not for *hail from*).  And I know it does for obsolete and archaic. Its entry is, simply ***to hail from (a place):** said of a vessel in reference to the port from which she has sailed; hence transf. of a person, to come from.*

Comment: I quite agree that *to hail from X* isn't in the least "formal". It's *colloquial, dated, dialectal, folksy, quaint* - but *formal* it ain't.

Answer (score 0):

I hail from Swat vs I belong to Swat

If you want to say that some place is your place of birth, or the place where you live, you usually use the phrasal verb "come from'. For example:

I come from Swat.

You can also use the phrasal verb "hail from" instead,  but it's usually used in formal English.

As for the use of the phrase 'belong to' in this sense, it's correct grammatically, though old-fashioned. It's true that we usually use this phrase in this sense in Pakistan.

Comment: When did *hail from* become  formal English?

Comment: This is what Oxford, McMillan, Cambridge dictionaries say.

Comment: [I guess we'll see](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317307/is-hail-from-somewhere-necessarily-formal-english)...

Comment: Khan, do you speak "Pakistani English"? If so, this question could be asking about the English spoken in Pakistan, and not general English.

Comment: @AlanCarmack, I am from Pakistan and I try my best to speak English the way it's generally spoken.